# Importing Boostrap4 into angular2 CLI

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am learning Angular2 CLI into my http://localhost:4200/. I followed https://cli.angular.io/ the tutorial and installed Angular2 successfully.

I have the problem with importing bootstrap4 css in this. I have tried the following code into my `src/angular.json` file.

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/assets/css/style.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "src/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
  "src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

I have added the bootstrap sample navbar into my `app.component.html`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> I am getting the `[WDS] Disconnected!` error in my local.

[image: My screen]

I have tried adding `import 'src/assets/css/bootstrap.css';` into my `style.css` but its working as a inline style not getting desired output.

If I tried to include `index.html` header using `<link src=""` its working but I don't want to use this method. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried changing the path for css file in the app.component.ts file. `styleUrls: [' path_to_css_file ']`

Comment: @LahiruMirihagoda I almost achieved everything by reinstalling `angular-cli` except the `[WDS] Disconnected!` error in Firefox.

Comment: I do not think this has  anything to do with css. So if you can check this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4839

Comment: @LahiruMirihagoda Not understand the github link. Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command,

```
npm install bootstrap@4 jquery --save
```

After edit the Angular.json file modify `"style"

```
["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"]`
```

&

```
"script:["/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"]`and ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/ js/boostrap.js"`]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not 100% answer your question, but if you are planning to use Bootstrap within your Angular project, I would recommend you to use [ng-bootstrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead, as it is fully compatible with Angular, and most importantly, there is not need to install Jquery.

1) To install it, simply run `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

2) To install any Bootstrap components such as modals and alerts into your component, you can simply import the required Bootstrap modules into your module by doing this: `import { NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

Comment: Sorry I don't want to use `ng-bootstrap`.

Comment: @Saravana understand. Anyways, I have used a similar approach as you when it comes to installing bootstrap css.. I extracted it and included in `styles` of `angular.json`. There shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Okay. I will try to reinstall again.

Comment: `[WDS] Disconnected!` error. do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and import it from node modules folder into your style.css

Comment: This method installed all dist files including lot of libraries.

Comment: just import the bootstrap.min.css file, should be in dist/assets/css/

Comment: I tried. But it will install all bootstrap libraries like `_scss`

Comment: `[WDS] Disconnected!` error. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: WDS : Webpack Developer Server, if it happened after you imported the bootstrap, check your import, and also check in console and chrome developer tools for any error logs.

Comment: It's not an answer, but NOT put css in assets directory. Angular minimify all the .css in an unique .css, (and copy the assets file). So you needn't export too

Comment: @AdityaThakur This problem with Firefox only